# PHP - Extract a slice of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of key values that looks like this:

```
array(5) {
  ["2014-04-24"]=>
  int(5)
  ["2014-04-25"]=>
  int(2)
  ["2014-04-27"]=>
  int(1)
  ["2014-04-29"]=>
  int(7)
  ["2014-05-2"]=>
  int(7)
}
```

Lets say I want to array_slice so that it becomes like this:

```
array(3) {
  ["2014-04-25"]=>
  int(2)
  ["2014-04-27"]=>
  int(1)
  ["2014-04-29"]=>
  int(7)
}
```

How do we do this since there is no number indexes?

I have tried the `array_slice($theArray, '2014-04-24', '2014-04-29')` but that didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`array_slice` expects offset index and length as parameter.

So, what you are looking for is:

```
array_slice($theArray, 1, 3);
```

It will return you 3 elements starting from the 1st position (counting starts at zero).